# What's the difference between official builds and GraphicAll builds?

Tags: versions

I want to get a lot of performance in rendering, but I also want stability and useful features that can be included in Blender builds.

GraphicAll builds seem to be geared towards a more specific set of features people might want, and they may include extra CUDA kernels (Blender reports that my card is 1.1, but the specifications don't say anything about it).

Should I stick to official builds from the Blender Foundation, or are GraphicAll builds more suited towards my needs? What's the difference, anyway?

Comment: I think GraphicALL builds often have extra patches or CUDA kernels not in master. Note that as of blender 2.7, only GPU's with a cuda compute ranking of 2.0 or greater are officially supported, but it [is possible to get older GPUs working](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1448/599).

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm not seeing a solution there, but I've tried lots of GraphicAll builds and no luck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You need to compile blender with the sm_13 kernel. However, It may not be worth the effort, depending on your GPU (it could be slower than your CPU, and many features are not supported on older GPUs).

Comment: @gandalf3 Found some supported builds at http://www.graphicall.org/bat3a and my GPU was 3x faster than my CPU in viewport renders. Don't know why people (not you specifically) think that older means slower 99% of the time.