# Cuda acceleration with CUDA 1.2

Tags: rendering, linux, gpu

I've got a GeForce 330M and CUDA 1.2 as a consequence.

But Blender supports only >=2.0.

I read this [page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/GPU_Rendering) and they say that I have to use Cuda toolkit 5.0.

BUT:

- the link leads to toolkit 6.0.37

  => I try with this one.
- When I try to install it (32 bit .run for ubuntu 13.04 (I've got 14.04))
  I've got this error:

> Using more to view the EULA.
>   Error: unsupported compiler: 4.8.2. Use --override to override this check.
>   Missing recommended library: libGLU.so
>   Missing recommended library: libXi.so
>   Missing recommended library: libXmu.so
>
> Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-6.0
>
> ===========
>
> ## = Summary =
>
> Driver:   Not Selected
>   Toolkit:  Installation Failed. Using unsupported Compiler.
>   Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-6.0
>
> Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_3711.log

Which compiler?

Is there another solution?

thanks!

Updates:

- I just realised that they write just after the link "The CUDA toolkit 5.0 **(64-bit version)** or newer must be installed for this."

What should I do? Install a 64 bit on a 32 bit system (it's my test external hdd) ?

Comment: There is a difference between the CUDA *Compute ability* and the version of the *CUDA Toolkit*. A 330M has a *Compute ability* of 1.2 (see this [list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)), and unfortunately no amount of driver/software updates will change that. [Blender dropped support for GPUs with < 2.0 *Compute ability*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1448/599). While it's still possible to get working, it might well be not worth it.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler the error message talks about is the gcc C compiler. Nvidia's nvcc compiler (which comiles the cuda code) does not work with gcc-4.8. I think the version you need is gcc-4.6.
I had the same problem. I had to install gcc 4.6 and then set the link `gcc` to gcc-4.6. It is normally set to the newest version of the compiler (gcc-4.8 in your case). There is also an [answer that could help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380609/anyone-has-successfully-installed-cuda-5-5-on-ubuntu-13-10-64-bit) on Ask Ubuntu.

However, as @gandalf3 mentioned in the comments to your question, this will not help you with using cycles. The compute capability of your card is just too low. It does not support certain features that cycles needs.

Comment: Thank you! So is it no use to make it work? Is there a solution? (I've got a laptop Toshiba A660)

Comment: The blender [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/GPU_Rendering)

Comment: thanks but I already read it and didn't found any other help that it wont work (well or at all). I wanted to ask if there is no other way that to change the computer? Should I try an older version of Blender?

Comment: Oh sorry, my commnent was actually longer. I don't know what happened to the rest of it. Of course you can try an older version of Blender, I think the pre-2.67 releases still support older graphics cards. But they might be missing some features that the newer Blender releases have and are probably slower when rendering. What you can try with the current Blender version is enabling the experimental feature set, as the wiki says. For this you need the Cuda Toolkit 5.0. If you are lucky Blender can still compile the Cuda shaders for your graphics card at runtime.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that all rendering features will work correctly. Also, I am not sure if this will decrease you rendering time much. You card only has 48 cores, which all run slower than a typical CPU. Combined with the limited memory bandwidth of the GPU and the bad branching behavior GPU rendering might actually be slower than CPU rendering for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! So if I use 2.67, it might work. OK i'll test it this afternoon! And I've got a GeForce 330M, and if I use it, it will be slower if I am right? (I can't really imagine slower than with my CPU ;p ) And for 2.70 with the toolkit, I don't know how to link gcc, so I will do this version at last, after some documentation! I'll keep you informed!

Comment: I think you need a pre-2.67 release, meaning 2.66 or earlier. It might be slower than your CPU, especially if your CPU has multiple cores, but that depends on what CPU you actually have of course. What I meant with the link is that if you type `gcc` in your command line there is a link with the name gcc that points to a specific version of the compiler. If I remember correctly, this link is in the same directors as the gcc executable. You have to make the link point to the correct version of gcc so that Cuda can find it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! So gcc has to point to an other executable (the 2.6 version), right? I tried many versions of Blender, and actually, it works with Experimental in 2.69! I tested many versions without Experimental and then 2.67 and 2.69 with. It worked with both, Experimental enabled. And the test render (default scene) shows that it's quicker with GPU rendering! The only last problem is that Blender always reload something when I want to render it, and says that it may (and it does!) take time at the first use. But, given that it doesn't save anything, I have to do it at every start up!

Comment: And the point is, that my computer always overheats! But that's an other problem! Thanks to everybody!