# How can I render with GPU on iMac 09' NVIDIA GeForce 9400 256 MB?

Tags: rendering, gpu

I'm new to blender and just found out that GPU rendering is way faster than CPU rendering, so I decided download a few drivers that would allow me to render with my GPU. All went well, and I have the option to render with either the GPU or CPU now, but, when I click the render button, a message saying "cuda device supported only with compute compablility 2.0 or up, found 1.1."

Next I tried changing "feature set" to "experimental," but still nothing.

Any suggestion as to how I can fix this?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1475/1853

Comment: With only 16 cuda cores (according to the Nvidia website) and with so little RAM, I doubt it's worth the trouble enabling GPU rendering with that card at all. I don't think you are going to see any increase in speed and you are going to run out of memory very quick...

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to find clear information, but if [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is to be believed, the GeForce 9400 is supported by CUDA 1.x, but not 2.x which is what Cycles uses (look for the chart). This would be why it says "found 1.1," which is what comes with the driver.

That being said, there seem to be rumors in the deep web... whispers of dark magics... that will allow the 9400GT to run some newer versions of CUDA. Of such things... I hope never to be openly spoken in the halls of men.

Comment: could you direct me to a source where i can find such information?