# Geforce 210 with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

As a present I got the Asus Geforce 210. I know that it is a very cheap graphics card, but is it possible to use it for cycles rendering?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Blender 2.75a with support enabled (automatically) for Geforce 210. To check if itsn't a mistake, I enabled and disabled before rendering a scene. Yes, it works with your CUDA, NVIDIA GeForce 210. However, the latest RC version 2.76 don't detected my card (yet). Check if your NVIDIA drivers are updated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9SvB.jpg

Comment: Thanks for this info. I have installed the nvidia-current package. I have to try it the next time..

Comment: Oh sorry. I remembered something. Blender also detects the card, but it says that it has an older version on it..

Answer (score 5):

Your card is no longer supported supported starting with blender 2.67.
Quote from the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html):

> NVIDIA CUDA is supported for GPU rendering with NVIDIA graphics cards. We support graphics cards starting from GTX 4xx (computing capability 2.0).

And even if you made it work, ([See this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-enable-gpu-rendering-on-older-nvidia-gpus)) that card has only 16 cuda cores. Rendering on CPU is going much faster...

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I thought it would be better than rendering with my dual core celeron...