# CUDA option not shown when using an old GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine

It looks like this is a common problem, but I can't find any forum post that has a solution to my situation: I have no CUDA tab in system settings in Blender.

My data:
Windows 10 64bit

Blender v2.77

Geforce GT 330M - driver Nvidia 341.95 (newest avalible driver.)

Is there someone who can help me to find out what can be the issue?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried everything outlined in [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599)?

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using, notebook or desktop / tower? Going to [this nvidia page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#collapse4), and clicking to expand the section "Cuda enabled GeForce products", I don't see that the GeForce GT 330 M included in the list.

Comment: i am using notebook on my notebook is a sticker saying Geforce with CUDA. so i suppose that it is supported. i can also finde CUDA settings in the nvidia control pannel.

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck.

The graphics card in question is quite old and has a [Cuda compute capability 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), which is not supported in blender anymore

To use GPU rendering in Blender you need a card with a 2.0 compute capability.

Form the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html):

> NVIDIA CUDA is supported for GPU rendering with NVIDIA graphics cards. We support graphics cards starting from GTX 4xx (computing capability 2.0).

read:
[How to enable GPU rendering on older Nvidia GPUs?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-enable-gpu-rendering-on-older-nvidia-gpus)

and
[Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles/7486#7486)

Even if you where able to somehow hack GPU rendering with that card, it is likely going to be equal or slower than rendering on CPU.