# Tesla C1060 not seen by Blender after install

Tags: gpu

Sorry if this question has been asked but search results didn't show it.
I just bought a Nvidia C1060 Tesla card with 4GB memory, it's a fairly old card. I was hoping to use it with Blender but after install and driver install I do not see it listed as a choice in Blender. I did check device manager and it's there and installed correctly. Am I missing something here? I've also installed the Cuda drivers. This is a Noob question for sure but I thought Blender would automatically see it and give me the choice to use it.

Comment: That's a pretty exotic card, it may not be supported under Cycles. In theory every CUDA capable card should be supported, in practice every hardware a Blender developer doesn't have access to, is untested and therefore may not work, or work but suffer from sub-optimal performance.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Just to clarify, only CUDA cards  with compute capability of 2.0 or higher will work on cycles. The card in question has a lower compute capability. Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA and https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/how-to-enable-gpu-rendering-on-older-nvidia-gpus

Comment: Hum forgot about that detail, since the poster mentioned he just bought it, I just assumed it was a recent card with higher CUDA compute version. Good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card is not supported. It has a CUDA compute capability 1.3. Support for cards with compute capability less than 2.0 was dropped a few versions ago.

Quoting from the [Blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html):

> CUDA
>
> Nvidia CUDA is supported for GPU rendering with Nvidia graphics cards. We support graphics cards starting from GTX 4xx (computing capability 2.0).

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the input. Do you know what the last Blender version that supported this card would be?